# Umbraco 7 Custom Field Indexing issues with GetPropertyValue

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

Having an issue with custom index fields for RTE properties (Other property types seem to be working fine).

Version : 7.3.6

Summary of issue: When trying to access RTE properties on OnApplicationStarted appending to the event GatheringNodeData an error is thrown:

```
System.NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2147467261
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=umbraco
  StackTrace:
       at Umbraco.Web.Templates.TemplateUtilities.ParseInternalLinks(String text, Boolean preview)
       at Umbraco.Web.PropertyEditors.ValueConverters.RteMacroRenderingValueConverter.ConvertDataToSource(PublishedPropertyType propertyType, Object source, Boolean preview)
       at Umbraco.Web.PublishedCache.XmlPublishedCache.XmlPublishedProperty.<.ctor>b__0()
       at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
       at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
       at Umbraco.Web.PublishedCache.XmlPublishedCache.XmlPublishedProperty.<.ctor>b__1()
       at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
       at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
       at CreativeJar.Wickes.BrandingPortal.CMS.Handlers.OnApplicationStart.GatheringNodeDataHandler(Object sender, IndexingNodeDataEventArgs e, UmbracoHelper helper) in D:\CodeChronicles\CreativeJar\Branding Portal\Trunk\Code\Wickes.BrandingPortal.CMS\Handlers\OnApplicationStart.cs:line 64
       at CreativeJar.Wickes.BrandingPortal.CMS.Handlers.OnApplicationStart.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<OnApplicationStarted>b__0(Object sender, IndexingNodeDataEventArgs e) in D:\CodeChronicles\CreativeJar\Branding Portal\Trunk\Code\Wickes.BrandingPortal.CMS\Handlers\OnApplicationStart.cs:line 35
       at Examine.Providers.BaseIndexProvider.OnGatheringNodeData(IndexingNodeDataEventArgs e) in x:\Projects\Examine\Examine\Projects\Examine\Providers\BaseIndexProvider.cs:line 190
       at UmbracoExamine.UmbracoContentIndexer.OnGatheringNodeData(IndexingNodeDataEventArgs e)
       at Examine.LuceneEngine.Providers.LuceneIndexer.GetDataToIndex(XElement node, String type) in x:\Projects\Examine\Examine\Projects\Examine\LuceneEngine\Providers\LuceneIndexer.cs:line 1113
       at Examine.LuceneEngine.Providers.LuceneIndexer.ProcessIndexQueueItem(IndexOperation op, IndexWriter writer) in x:\Projects\Examine\Examine\Projects\Examine\LuceneEngine\Providers\LuceneIndexer.cs:line 1802
       at Examine.LuceneEngine.Providers.LuceneIndexer.ProcessQueueItem(IndexOperation item, ICollection`1 indexedNodes, IndexWriter writer) in x:\Projects\Examine\Examine\Projects\Examine\LuceneEngine\Providers\LuceneIndexer.cs:line 1580
       at Examine.LuceneEngine.Providers.LuceneIndexer.ForceProcessQueueItems(Boolean block) in x:\Projects\Examine\Examine\Projects\Examine\LuceneEngine\Providers\LuceneIndexer.cs:line 1537
  InnerException:
```

Hookup Code:

```
var helper = new UmbracoHelper(UmbracoContext.Current);
            ExamineManager.Instance.IndexProviderCollection["ContentIndexer"].GatheringNodeData += (sender, e) => GatheringNodeDataHandler(sender, e, helper);
```

Error is being thrown here:

```
foreach (var prop in WidgetProperties.Where(prop => widget.HasProperty(prop) && widget.HasValue(prop)))
                {
                    content.Append(widget.GetPropertyValue<string>(prop));
                }
```

To isolate the issue I tried accessing a RTE property directly with the same results.

```
var node = helper.TypedContent(e.NodeId);
var test = node.GetPropertyValue("pageSummary");
```

Running HasProperty & Has Value returns true

Looking in the immediate window, I can see the value when doing GetProperty("pageSummary") however attempting to access this property throws the same exception,

Unfortunately I am unable to step into the call bur the stack trace seems to indicate that there could be a dependency that is not available at the point of execution.

Does anyone know if I am attempting to do this at the wrong point of execution?

I have tried ways to get the raw value (I am not really concerned about actual links parsing etc which seems to be causing the issue) however at the moment I have had no luck.

Many thanks

Les

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to have been an issue for some time:
(UmbracoContext is not available at the calling method resulting in the error)
http://issues.umbraco.org/issue/U4-5953?preventRedirect=true

Which is a little weird as I am sure I had this working in 7.3.4 (before updating to 7.3.5 then 7.3.6) as the search functionality and indexes were updating.

It also didn't help that I made the mistake of assuming it was only RTE properties but it seems its all string based ones.

In the end I found two ways to get the functionality I wanted the first being:

```
IContentService cs = ApplicationContext.Current.Services.ContentService;

            var node1 = cs.GetById(e.NodeId);
            var widgets1 = node1.Descendants().Where(x => x.ContentType.Alias.Contains("Widget"));
            var content1 = new StringBuilder();

            foreach (var widget in widgets1)
            {
                foreach (var prop in WidgetProperties.Where(prop => widget.HasProperty(prop)))
                {
                    content1.Append(widget.GetValue(prop));
                    content1.Append(" ");
                }
            }

            var result = content1.ToString();
```

The problem with the method above was that it wasn't getting all the descendants just the first level.

The next solution got the results I was expecting but due to its greedy nature (not found a nice way of only getting the nodes I want) a fair bit slower. As its a small site and only effects the content editors it seems like a necessary evil.

```
 var node = new Node(e.NodeId);

            var widgets = node.GetDescendantNodes();

            var content = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (var widget in widgets)
            {
                foreach (var prop in WidgetProperties.Where(prop => widget.HasProperty(prop)))
                {
                    content.Append(widget.GetProperty(prop));
                    content.Append(" ");
                }
            }

            e.Fields.Add("pageContent", content.ToString());
```

I am not sure if this issue will be fixed any time soon as the Umbraco team seem to be pushing the Grid editor pretty hard (over node based components/widgets).